How can I deal with errors in the controller?
How can I solve this problem: I want to build an Express application. By following mvc, I want to create a service that connects to the Github API using axios. How can I deal with errors in the controller?
this is my services :
import axios from 'axios';
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.github.com/',
});


export async function getUserData (githubToken: string)
{
  
  const response = await axiosInstance.get('user', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `token ${ githubToken }`,
    },
  });
  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error("Invalid Token")
  }
  return response.data
}


I'm trying to catch errors with the controller
